# prevent break after \poemtitle

Tags: page-breaking, verse

This MWE shows that LaTeX can put a break after the title of a poem (written with the `\poemtitle` command of the `verse` package). Can someone advice me a way to prevent this behaviour?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{verse}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
text

\lipsum[2-6]
\poemtitle{Poem title}
\begin{verse}
first\\
second
\end{verse}
text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you add the following code to your preamble, the page break should go away.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@vstypeptitle}[1]{%
  \vspace{\beforepoemtitleskip}
  {\poemtitlefont #1\par}\nobreak
  \vspace{\afterpoemtitleskip}
}
\makeatother
```

the change was to add `\nobreak` after the title.

in my opinion, this is a bug, or at least a misfeature, and you would be doing a service to report it to the author of the `verse` package.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. I've written to Will Robertson.